Set root user from Dockerfile
I am trying to create a user inside docker container using the following dockerfile. I will be accessing this container using slurm job, so I need a root user inside container to install packages and all. The problem with this script is that it sets a password, so everytime I run a slurm job, the operation is stuck at [sudo] password for cedsan: line as I can see from the logs of the slurm job.
Either I need to set a root user through dockerfile, or somehow I need to give the password to the container when prompted through the slurm job itself.
Kindly suggest.
Dockerfile:
FROM nvidia/cuda:12.2.0-devel-ubuntu22.04

# Set environment variable for non-interactive apt-get installs

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

#set environment variables for user credentials obtained by step 2, password can be of users choice

ENV dockerusername=cedsan

ENV dockeruserpassword=password

ENV dockerusergroupid=1029

ENV dockeruserid=17234

ENV dockerusergroupname=ced_san

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda.sh && bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda && rm /tmp/miniconda.sh

ENV PATH=/opt/miniconda/bin:$PATH

# Update the package list and install necessary packages

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo \

python3 \

python3-pip \

build-essential \

gcc \

g++ \

openmpi-bin \

openmpi-common \

libopenmpi-dev

# Install NumPy and SciPy

RUN pip3 install numpy scipy

#Create group and user

RUN groupadd $dockerusergroupname -g $dockerusergroupid

RUN useradd $dockerusername -u $dockeruserid -g $dockerusergroupid -d /home/$dockerusername

RUN mkdir -p /home/$dockerusername && chown -R $dockerusername:$dockerusergroupid /home/$dockerusername

#Set user password

RUN echo "$dockerusername:$dockeruserpassword" | chpasswd

#Add user to sudo group

RUN usermod -aG sudo $dockerusername

#Switch to the user for all subsequent commands

USER $dockerusername

# Set a working directory

WORKDIR /raid/cedsan/new_docker/

SLURM script:
#!/bin/sh

#SBATCH --job-name=serial_job_test ## Job name

#SBATCH --ntasks=1 ## Run on a single CPU can take upto 10

#SBATCH --time=24:00:00 ## Time limit hrs:min:sec, its specific to queue being used

#SBATCH --output=serial_test_job.out ## Standard output

#SBATCH --error=serial_test_job.err ## Error log

#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1 ## GPUs needed, should be same as selected queue GPUs

#SBATCH --partition=q_1day-1G ## Specific to queue being used, need to select from queues available

#SBATCH --mem=20GB ## Memory for computation process can go up to 100GB

pwd; hostname; date |tee result

##example for above looks like( do not include these 2 highlighted lines in your script):

docker run -t --gpus '"device='$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'"' --name $SLURM_JOB_ID --ipc=host --shm-size=20GB --user $(id -u $USER):$(id -g $USER) -v /raid/cedsan/new_docker pymatgen_cuda bash -c "sudo apt-get update" | tee -a log_out.txt


what does the contents of the /etc/sudoers file look like? cant you just update that with the user and commands with  NOPASS so it doesnt prompt for it?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password

If you're going to try to set that up, it will probably be easier to just run your container as root; use a docker run -u root option or set USER root in the Dockerfile (it will probably also work to delete the existing USER line).  Note that any ENV directive will be clearly visible in the image's docker history and you almost definitely do not want to put any sort of credentials there.
